# Adding new rows into query from nonexistent data in the database table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sample table:

```
+----------+------+-------+
|   DATE   | NAME | HOURS |
+----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-3 | JOHN |   8   |
+----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-9 | JOHN |   5   |
+----------+------+-------+
```

How can I generate a query that fills new rows to the existent data, e.g, sample query result:

```
+-----------+------+-------+
|   DATE    | NAME | HOURS |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-1  | JOHN |   0   |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-2  | JOHN |   0   |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-3  | JOHN |   8   |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-4  | JOHN |   0   |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-5  | JOHN |   0   |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-6  | JOHN |   0   |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-7  | JOHN |   0   |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-8  | JOHN |   0   |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-9  | JOHN |   5   |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 2018-5-10 | JOHN |   0   |
+-----------+------+-------+
```

Check that I've added 0 into HOURS column because JOHN doesn't appear with hours in the specified date (only in 2018-5-3 and 2018-5-8). I am currently trying to get this result. This is only the begin of a big table I need to process, so I'll need to generate this fixed values per user. I was trying using left/right join with previously generated dates but it didn't work.

Can you advice me the best way to accomplish it? Thanks.

Comment: Generate_series should get you there https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `generate_series()` and `left join`:

```
select g.dte, t.name, coalesce(t.hours, 0) as hours
from generate_series('2018-05-01'::date, '2018-05-10'::date, interval '1 day') g(dte) left join
     t 
     on g.dte = t.date;
```

For multiple users, you need to generate all the rows for all the users and then `left join`:

```
select g.dte, n.name, coalesce(t.hours, 0) as hours
from generate_series('2018-05-01'::date, '2018-05-10'::date, interval '1 day'
                    ) g(dte) cross join
     (select distinct name from t) n left join
     t 
     on g.dte = t.date and n.name = t.name;
```